# How to create another partition without losing data for installing Windows 7 along with Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, partitioning, windows-installation

I like Windows 7, but I also want to keep Windows 10 along with it which I have already installed after upgrading from Windows 8.1.

Question is that can I install Windows 7 after installing Windows 10 because I know I can install Windows 10 after installing Win 7, but how about the opposite?

If I can install, then how can I create another partition for it WITHOUT affecting the DATA of current partitions? I heard about the "Shrink" feature of drives from the Computer Management. Is it safe? I mean does it create a new drive by collecting free space from more than one drives WITHOUT affecting any data?

**NOTE:** I have two drives right now, one for Windows 10 and the other one for DATA. I am interested in taking free spaces from these two drives into new drive for Windows 7 installation without affecting data

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up the Disk Management and select Shrink on any of the Devices. Windows will only allow you to shrink the Drive, without losing data. If you want a separata 2nd Drive, you can do the same to the other Hard Drive.

Afterwards boot from the Windows7 DVD and install Windows 7 on the free space. Windows will modify the Bootloader and add another entry.